# oft outlook vba string replace not works oft mail with table

Tags: vba, email, outlook

want to replace some string in oft outlook mail file.have written the below code 
but oft file has table which is not displaying if i use MyItem.HTMLBody. is there any alternative ?

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim up As Object
    Dim ation As Object
    Dim hsbcval As Object

    up = TextBox1.Text
    ation = TextBox2.Text
    hsbcval = TextBox3.Text

    myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    MyItem = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("D:\this.oft")
     MyItem.HTMLBody = Replace(MyItem.HTMLBody, "IDSPUPZ", up)
     MyItem.HTMLBody = Replace(MyItem.HTMLBody, "HANMZ", ation)
     MyItem.HTMLBody = Replace(MyItem.HTMLBody, "HSBCVALZ", hsbcval)
    MyItem.Display()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you get as a result of replace actions a valid HTML markup.

Second, Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup and not all HTML tags/elements are supported. Read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Make sure the result HTML markup are rendered in Word properly.

And, finally, make sure that the [BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869979.aspx) property is set to HTML. The body text format determines the standard used to display the text of the message. Microsoft Outlook provides three body text format options: Plain Text, Rich Text (RTF), and HTML. Be aware, all text formatting will be lost when the BodyFormat property is switched from RTF to HTML and vice-versa.